# Обращение к подэлементу

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть меню

```html
sidemenu.innerHTML=`<li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  </li>`;
```

Есть элемент этого списка

```js
let elemmenuitemli = document.querySelectorAll('li');
```

```html
<li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Каким образом можно обратиться к подэлементам `elemmenuitemli` - элементам классов `.centerplace` и `.rightside`?

Comment: так же через `querySelector` например

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а селектор какой? я понимаю как глобально в документе найти, а как внутри уже существующего отбора (не из всего документа, а только подобласти всего документа) я не знаю?

Comment: точно так же, как в документе, только точка будет не из `document`, а уже из найденного элемента. например `querySelector('#test').querySelector('.hello').querySelector('who-is-it')`

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить, о вашем втором куске кода, то можно добраться до элементов через childNodes и получить коллекцию, в которой li будет первым (нулевым) элементом. После этого, можно получить детей нулевого элемента коллекции, в которой будут нужные вам элементы. Не знаю, то ли это, что вы хотели узнать, но добраться к элементам так можно.
let elems = document.querySelectorAll("li");

elems[0].children

HTMLCollection(3) [div.leftside, div.centerplace, div.rightside]

Comment: а `let elemcenterplace = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li>.centerplace');
let elemrightside = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li>.rightside');` использовать можно?

Comment: let elemrightside = document.querySelector('.rightside')
let elemcenterplace = document.querySelector('centerplace')